# Document preprocessing libraries

Tags: itext, apache-poi, java

I'm looking for libararies (and guides) for document preprocessing. I mean, for example like generating PDF, MS Office (Excel/Word), Open Office format files.

I've seen that there's popular especially Apache POI and iText. 
Do you know any book that describes doc preprocessing libaries (for iText I found "iText in Action")?

I also would like to compare libraries.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

For the file formats themselves, many of the details are available online. There are no books that I know of. But here are some online references to some of the office document file formats.

For Microsoft Office documents (Word, Excel, PowerPoint), the formats are published
http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/osp/office-file-formats/default.aspx
or
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313105%28v=office.12%29.aspx

The Microsoft site contains some examples of how to parse Office type files, which may be useful to you.

For Open Office, you could look at
http://www.openoffice.org/xml/general.html
or 
https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office

But the above are more like reference manuals than a tutorial or a library that lets you parse these documents easily.